# What does F[YY]e mean in reporting

Tags: financial-statements

What does the term F[YY]e mean in financial reporting in India? I have seen reports these days to use the term F15e. Does this mean Financial Year end?
Googling on this does not yield a relevant result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means it's estimate and not final numbers and generally used for future years

Comment: Then probably I looked at a older report. Thanks Dheer. It makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

that means fiscal year 2015,Most internal company in China or India have different fiscal year to estimate financial state when it run to the end of year